# How to retrieve videos from folders?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, video, android-mediaplayer

Hello I'm new in Android Studio and I really don't know how fix this problem, I really tried every thing but I can't solve this.

**Problem:**
I'm trying to retrieve videos from folders but it's not
happening, you can see down below in the exampe images:
[example image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuNpN.png) and [example image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLMBF.png).

Here are codes of videofileActivity, maybe there be a problem I couldn't see, so please check it.

```
    public class videoFileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private   RecyclerView recyclerView;

    private ArrayList<MediaFill> videoFileArraylist = new ArrayList<>();

  private   VideoFileAdapter  videoFileAdapter;

   private String folderName;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_file);
        folderName = getIntent().getStringExtra("folderName");
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(folderName);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.video_rv);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this , RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(videoFileAdapter);
        showVideoFile();
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    private void showVideoFile() {
        videoFileArraylist = getVideoFile(folderName);
        if(folderName != null && videoFileArraylist.size()>0){
            videoFileAdapter = new VideoFileAdapter(videoFileArraylist,this);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(videoFileAdapter);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false));
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "can't find any video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
    @SuppressLint("StringFormatInvalid")
    private ArrayList<MediaFill> getVideoFile(String folder_Name){
        ArrayList<MediaFill> videoFile = new ArrayList<>();

        String[] projection = {
                MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA,MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION,MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE,
        };

        String selection = MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA + " like?";
        String[] selectionArg = new String[]{"%"+folder_Name+"%"};
        Cursor cursor =getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,projection,selection,selectionArg,null);
        if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToNext()){
            do{
                String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID));
                String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE));
                String size = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE));
                String displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String duration = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION));
                String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA));
                String dataAdded = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED));
              MediaFill mediaFill= new MediaFill(id, id,title,size,dataAdded,duration,displayName,path);

                videoFileArraylist.add(mediaFill);
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return videoFile;
    }



}
```

Below is the folder Adapter, please check this out too

```
    public class VideoFileAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VideoFileAdapter.ViewHolder> {
   private final ArrayList<MediaFill> videoList ;
    private final Context context;


    public VideoFileAdapter(ArrayList<MediaFill> videoList, Context context) {
        this.videoList = videoList;
        this.context = context;

    }



    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        CardView v = (CardView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.vidoe_item, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.videoName.setText(videoList.get(position).getDisplayName());
        String size = videoList.get(position).getSize();
        holder.videoSize.setText(Formatter.formatFileSize(context,Long.parseLong(size)));
        double milliseconds = Double.parseDouble(videoList.get(position).getDuration());
        holder.videoDuration.setText(timeConversion((long) milliseconds));
        Glide.with(context).load(new File(videoList.get(position).getPath())).into(holder.Thumbnail);

        holder.menu_more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Menu more", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Playing video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        AtomicReference<ArrayList<MediaFill>> videoList = new AtomicReference<>(new ArrayList<>());

        return videoList.get().size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView Thumbnail , menu_more;
        TextView videoName, videoSize, videoDuration;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            Thumbnail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            menu_more = itemView.findViewById(R.id.video_menu_more);
            videoName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.video_name);
            videoDuration = itemView.findViewById(R.id.video_duration);
            videoSize = itemView.findViewById(R.id.video_size);

        }
    }
     @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
     public String timeConversion(long value){
        String videoTime;
        int duration = (int) value;
        int hrs = (duration/3600000);
        int mns = (duration/60000)%60000;
        int sec = duration%60000/1000;
        if (hrs > 0){
            videoTime = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",hrs, mns,sec);
        }else {
            videoTime = String.format("%02d:%02d", mns,sec);
        }
        return videoTime;

     }
}
```

Also it is a Mediafile

```
    public class MediaFill {
    private String id;
    private String title;
    private String displayName;
    private String size;
    private String duration;
    private String path;
    private String dateAdded;

    public MediaFill(String id, String title, String displayName, String size, String duration, String path, String dateAdded, String s) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.displayName = displayName;
        this.size = size;
        this.duration = duration;
        this.path = path;
        this.dateAdded = dateAdded;
    }

    public MediaFill(String path) {
       this.path  = path;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return displayName;
    }

    public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    public String getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(String size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public String getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(String duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public String getDateAdded() {
        return dateAdded;
    }

    public void setDateAdded(String dateAdded) {
        this.dateAdded = dateAdded;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you debugged your code?

Comment: `Hello I'm new in android studio and i really don't know how fix this problem, I really tried every thing but i can't get through this please help me` This does not belong in the title of a post. Please edit your title. The title should indicate your problem. Also never cry 'please help me'. We know that everybody comes here for help.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It will help you a lot

Answer (score 1):

You problem goes here in the adapter:

```java
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    AtomicReference<ArrayList<MediaFill>> videoList = new AtomicReference<>(new ArrayList<>());
    return videoList.get().size();
}
```

Here you create n new list which has a size 0. So, the number of items in the recycler view is 0. But, it should be the size of the list right? So, try this:

```java
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return videoList.size();
}
```

Comment: Sir, I tried that too but it still not working.

Comment: did you check if the list size is not 0?